# How to include css files using yarn pnp

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-v2

Ive created a new project and used yarn to install `reset-css` and `sass` package.
In my main stylesheet I now want to include the `reset.css` stylesheet from the installed package and build it with `sass`.

How can I locate where `reset-css` file is to get its path and how can I `@use`/`@import` it in my scss file?

Normally I could just reference it from node_modules but the folder does not exist anymore when using yarn pnp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Yarn Plug'n'Play (PnP), traditional disk-based `node_modules` directories are not created. Instead, Yarn manages the dependency resolution in-memory or via zip files, bypassing the need for these directories. But this new architecture poses a question: how do you refer to installed packages without a disk-based file path?

In Yarn PnP, you can typically import dependencies in your JavaScript files as you would normally, but for cases like CSS, it can be a bit tricky.

Here are some suggestions for importing `reset-css` in a Sass/SCSS file when using Yarn PnP:

#### Method 1: `resolutions` in `package.json`

1. Add `reset-css` to your `package.json` if you haven't already.

   ```json
   {
     "dependencies": {
       "reset-css": "^x.y.z"
     }
   }
   ```
2. Run `yarn install`.
3. Use Yarn's resolutions field to create a symlink that you can reference in your Sass file.

   ```json
   {
     "dependencies": {
       "reset-css": "^x.y.z"
     },
     "resolutions": {
       "**/reset-css": "portal:./path/to/symlink/reset-css"
     }
   }
   ```
4. In your Sass/SCSS file:

   ```scss
   @import "./path/to/symlink/reset-css/reset.css";
   ```

#### Method 2: `sass` `includePaths` Option

1. When you are running `sass` or using a build tool that uses `sass` (like Webpack's `sass-loader`), you can specify `includePaths` to include the Yarn cache directory.

   For example, in Webpack config:

   ```js
   {
     test: /\.scss$/,
     use: [{
       loader: 'sass-loader',
       options: {
         sassOptions: {
           includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, '.yarn/cache')],
         },
       },
     }]
   }
   ```
2. Then, you should be able to import `reset-css` in your `.scss` file like this:

   ```scss
   @import "reset-css/reset.css";
   ```

#### Method 3: Copy During Build

You could copy the `reset.css` into your source directory during a build step. The idea is to use build tooling to locate the file within the Yarn cache and copy it into your project so that it can be easily referenced.

1. Identify the package location in the Yarn cache.
2. Use build tools like Webpack or a script to copy the `reset.css` into your project directory.
3. Reference it like any other local stylesheet.

---

Choose the method that best suits your project structure and build process.